# The Server Tag is not well formed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been searching for a while now yet can not seem to find an answer.

All the cases that I have seen have had this issue fixed by simply changing the `"` to a `'`

Please see the code below to see what i currenty have.

```
<td><asp:Button ID='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "valueID")%>' runat="server" Text="Hello" OnClick="SomeStuff_Click" /></td>
```

Comment: Don't use dynamic ID's. Instead you could append   the valueID to the ID like `BtnStuff_1`.

Comment: Yes, if i changed it to ID="Test" for example the page will load without a problem

Comment: I would say it would work for Text attribute, but the ID attribute cannot be set like this.

Comment: I tried the Text attribute and it worked. Just a shame that the ID attribute wont work since thats what i need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that as className and search by $(".myClass") in js.. if thats what you trying to do.

```
<asp:Button ID="asda" ClassName='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "valueID")%>' runat="server" Text="Hello" OnClick="SomeStuff_Click" />
```